# How to restart Kestrel Hosted in Windows Service?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, windows-services, kestrel-http-server

I want to restart Kestrel (asp.net core 3.1) via an authorized http request.
Kestrel is contained in a Windows service configured to restart itself automatically upon failure.
As far as i know the simplest way is to return an exit code different from 0, windows will do all the rest.

In light of that, the code I wrote is actually simple:

```
        public MaintenanceController(IHostApplicationLifetime hostLifetime)
        {
            this.HostLifetime = hostLifetime ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hostLifetime));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("service/restart")]
        [Authorize("AdminOnly")]
        public ActionResult RestartService()
        {
                Program.IsRestart = true; //see below
                this.HostLifetime.StopApplication();

                //this does not work!
                if (HostLifetime is WindowsServiceLifetime lifetime)
                {
                    lifetime.ExitCode = 1;
                }
                //neither this!
                Environment.ExitCode = 1;

                return Ok();
        }
```

The only way to make windows restarts the service is just actually call

```
Environment.Exit(1);
```

without HostLifetime.StopApplication();

But the issue with Environment.Exit called alone is it causes a **non** graceful shutdown, something I want absolutely to avoid.

Another approach I tried, to force an exit code different from 0, which did not work, was to put in Startup.cs:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
        {
            [...]

            applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() =>
            {
                //this can be set in the controller
                if (Program.IsRestart)
                {
                    Environment.Exit(1); 
                }
            });
        }
```

but, when called after ApplicationStopped, Environment.Exit(1) does apparently nothing, in fact even inside event viewer there is no trace of the services' shutdown with error, so windows does nothing.

### UPDATE

Going back to classic, I changed the Main entry point to return an int and returned 1. 
Still windows does not restart the service nor a failure entry is written to event viewer. It looks like is always stopped gracefully

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working like it should. You may want to consider writing a wrapper batch file or watcher process.

Your watcher would wait for the process to exit, and if a flag file (e.g. `.staydown`) is present, it would exit gracefully. If the file doesn't exist, it would then restart the process.

In your `RestartService` method, use `Environment.Exit(0)` which would be a graceful shutdown, but since the `.staydown` file doesn't exist, your watcher would then restart the server.  Your watcher would only stop running if the `.staydown` file exists and then the server is stopped, or the Windows Service itself is stopped.

When your app starts up, be sure to delete `.staydown` if present.

If you have node installed, you might be able to use a utility like `forever` in place of the watcher batch file.

Comment: Environment.Exit(0) will cause the environment stop immediately, not a graceful shutdown. In fact, the  return Ok(); is not executed and the httprequest terminated abnormally. The error code 0 will just tell windows it was graceful when actually it wasn't. But apart from that I'm looking for an ideal solution without extra process

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the 'Enable actions for stops with errors' on the service, or run 'sc failureflag "My Service" 1'

More info here: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/06/servicebase-gotcha-recovery-actions.html

(this is a very strange behaviour on Windows part I think, honouring exit codes should be default!)